# Is there a way to hook ctag changes to git branch checkouts and pulls?

Tags: ide, version-control-systems, git, ctags

When I checkout different branches, I sometimes notice that files in the repo are not available to Vim plugins that search based on the ctags index.

I don't have a definitive test that's shown the files are missing due to versioning, but I usually notice that the missing files are those that were recently added.

I occasionally notice other missing lookups, e.g. with function names or other symbols, and assume it's the same matter.  I'll quickly provide any details if someone has ideas.

Comment: Are you doing the git checkouts and pulls from within Vim? This sounds like something to solve in git, independently of vim.

Comment: @Gilles I am not - all git changes are happening on my own in bash CLI.  But, if any thinks this makes it off-topic, the integration is specific to Vim, and I wasn't positive if the issue was caused by another matter that others have seen commonly

Comment: Thanks @carpetsmoker, I wanted to add the `ctags` tag, but didn't have the rep.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on how you update your ./tags file:

If you do not commit your ./tags file to your branch/repository you can use a git hook that calls `ctags -R .` on each pull/checkout you do - this way your ./tags file will always contain data on all present files in the current version you have checked out.

If you *do* want to commit your ./tags file, you can also save that to a hook on push/commit.

You *could* teach vim to do that, but this is something git can handle nicely for you.

Comment: Tim Pope [wrote a blog article](http://tbaggery.com/2011/08/08/effortless-ctags-with-git.html) a few years back that details how something like this can be done.

Comment: I don't check in the tags file, and I don't have an immediate sense of need to do this.  I'd actually never thought of it, and for ludicrously-large projects I can see the benefit.  Thanks for the edge case tip!  Do you know about those git hooks?  Pardon; I'm sure I can find this out one my own, in time.

Comment: @New Alexandria: if you want to learn more about git hooks, I suggest to check out your .git/hooks folder. By default there should be some example scripts in there to inspire you. For details check out the official documentation at: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks